# Google Contacts: Browse by Group, Sync

Tags: 14.04, sync, contacts

Running Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome 3.12 with an added Google account through Online Accounts, I automatically get incorporated calendar, email and contacts.

Alas, the Contacts application is close to useless for handling my Google contacts, as it shows **all** contacts. As Google saves any email address one sends a mail to under `Other Contacts`, this includes some 2700 contacts in my case.

But Google also allows one to group contacts, which is how I keep them sorted on my phone and online.

My question is:

Is there a desktop application/hack/fix that will allow me to show and sync my Google contacts, **based on their assigned groups?**

Comment: Don't use contact application. Use Evolution. `sudo apt-get install evolution`. Both uses EDS (`Evolution-data-server` backend)Then, sync Google Contacts with [SyncEvolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Thunderbird which is the default email application and install one extension- google contacts 0.7.12 and it will sync your contacts the way you have arranged them in your google account and you can also install Display Contact Photo 1.2.7 extension and it will also show the photos of the contacts if they are visible in the google account.

Installing the Lightning extension along with Google Calender 0.32 will enable you to sync your calendar with Thunderbird email as well. All work quite well with Thunderbird. Have been using it for over a year.

All changes you make in Thunderbird for contacts or calendar get reflected in your google account on the web and vice-versa

But be prepared to sacrifice about 150 MB of RAM when Thunderbird is running.

Cheers